# C++ template std::vector::iterator error

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator

In C++, I am trying to get a `std::vector::iterator` for my templated class. However, when I compile it, I get the errors: `error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iterator'`, `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`. I also get the warning: `warning C4346: 'std::vector<T>::iterator' : dependent name is not a type`:

```
#include <vector>
template<class T> class v1{
    typedef std::vector<T>::iterator iterator; // Error here
};
class v2{
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iterator; // (This works)
};
```

I have even tried

```
template<typename T> class v1{
    typedef std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
};
```

And

```
template<typename T = int> class v1{
    typedef std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: clang++ is known to have quite decent error messages, especially for these kind of errors. In this case, it says *error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::vector<T>::iterator'*. I recommend trying clang (e.g. in an online compiler) if you can't understand the error message from another compiler.

Comment: @DyP GCC has similar error messages.

Comment: @Rapptz Oh, indeed it has for this example :) well that's a surprise. I eventually switched from g++ to clang++ some time ago because the error messages became unreadable, albeit for more complicated cases.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` is a [*dependent name*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name), so you need a `typename` here to specify that it refers to a type. Otherwise it is assumed to refer to a non-type:

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
```